How to setup environmental variable from inside qmake .pro file on linux?
I need to setup environmental variable with path from inside the .pro file which of course builds tons of stuff. The path is known. The behavior I expect is:
# my_project.pro
DESTDIR=~/cool/path/to/a/file/

# exporting DESTDIR to environmental variable called ENV_VAR

# terminal
$ qmake my_project.pro
$ make 
# messages from make building stuff
$ echo $ENV_VAR
~/cool/path/to/a/file/

Doesn't matter which one of them (qmake or make) will export the variable.
I tried all sort of things, to no success, e.g.
# inside 
# attempt 1
QMAKE_POST_LINK += ENV_VAR=$$DESTDIR \
export ENV_VAR
# attempt 2
system(ENV_VAR=$$DESTDIR && export ENV_VAR)
# attempt 91345
system(ENV_VAR=$$DESTDIR)
system(export ENV_VAR)

Every attempt ended in:
# terminal
$ echo $ENV_VAR

$

If there is such possibility, I, apparently, can't manage to random-guess the correct syntax.
How should I do this?
I'm using latest Qt5 and Ubuntu 22.04 jammy

You can't set the env of the parent process

While this is basically impossible, because qmake runs as a child process, I could indeed imagine a workaround, if you switch from bash to fish. I've never tried it, but fish has a concept of "global" variables, where you can set a variable in one fish instance and have it available in all others. I guess they manage this via some shared data pool. Another possibility would be to have qmake write the content of the variable to some file, from where you can retrieve it in you controlling shell.

You cannot set the environment variables of a parent process.
When you call qmake, bash does a fork. That is basically copying the complete environment. In the forked process, qmake is executed, so in the copied environment, not in the original environment.
